# PS script failure 'AuthorizationManager check failed

Tags: powershell

Unable to run PS script on one of our machine, getting this error: Deployment failed on machine ...with following message : 'AuthorizationManager check failed.'  Checked and ExecutionPolicy is unrestricted

The execution policy (both 32 and 64 bit) is unrestricted. I also tried setting it to RemoteSigned.
I've also tried adding the remote server to the trusted sites, but that didn't change anything.
I have to say that this script runs perfectly on other machines in the same environment, and only fails on this one...